# Transition from one gradient to another in d3js

Tags: d3.js

In my chart i have a rectangle with a gradient

```
    barG.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("id", "my_rectangle")
          .attr("x", 0)
          .attr("y", 50)
          .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
          .attr("width", rectWidth)
          .attr("fill", rectColor);
```

Depends on data the function rectColor returns a gradient

```
function rectColor(d) {
    //set bar color 
    if (d.value <= d.limit) {
        return "url(#gradientRed)";
    } else {
        return "url(#gradientDefault)";
    }
}
;
```

A gradient looks like this

```
    var gradientDefault = defs
            .append("linearGradient")
            .attr("id", "gradientDefault")
            .attr("x1", "0%")
            .attr("x2", "0%")
            .attr("y1", "0%")
            .attr("y2", "100%")
            .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

    gradientDefault.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "0%")
            .attr("stop-color", defaultStyle.backgroundColor)
            .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    gradientDefault.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "100%")
            .attr("stop-color", defaultStyle.secondaryBackgroundColor)
            .attr("stop-opacity", 1);
```

How can i make a transition from one gradient to another?

I have tried

```
    // animation rectangle/bar
    rect.transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .attr("fill", rectColor);
```

but it doesn't work...

Here is the [jsfiddle-code](https://jsfiddle.net/juri33/8dcahbe4/5/). The data will be loaded dynamically.

Comment: Can you post a codepen / Plunker example ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/juri33/8dcahbe4/5/

Comment: Not a very smooth transition when using gradient but here is how to do it `.attr("fill", "blue")
    .transition()
    .ease("linear")
    .delay(750)
    .attr("fill", rectColor);` code here https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/sm41bL38/

Comment: i dont think, this is a transition - form me it looks like a hard attribute change